# PHP Find any array value in a string and show the found value

Tags: php, arrays, find

I hope you can help me, I have an array with some filter words:

```
$dang=array('foo','bar','baz','qux');
```

User can write a text, I am getting it in a variable:

```
$answ=$_GET[answ];
```

If user write a text like: "I like this cabaret, it's so foo.", I want to print this:

```
Found: bar
```

"bar" is found in "cabaret", (First ocurrence only).

I found this function here [Find first occurance of array value in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902417/find-first-occurance-of-array-value-in-a-string)

```
$firstMatch = array_shift(array_intersect(str_word_count(strtolower($answ), 1), $dang));
```

it's works, sadly it finds words only (text separated by spaces).

Any way to do it for full text?

Comment: Have you looked in the manual `strpos()` comes to mind

Comment: I tried iterating the array and search using stripos(), it's a good way to do it, do you know something 'shorter'? maybe a regular exp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop the array using `foreach()` and use `strpos()` to check if the value exists in the string:

```
$string = "Hello world";

foreach ( $dang as $dong ) {
    if ( strpos($string, $dong) !== false ) {
        echo "Found: ".$dong; 
    }
}
```

[`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns `false` if the needle was not found, otherwise the position of the start of the needle in the haystack (0 being the first character)

Comment: This answer is right. You should add a foreach to iterate your array with your filters and it'll do what you need.